# How to use gulp use-ref with sass

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-useref

In the project I have:

```
<!-- build:css css/error.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="src/assets/styles/_bootstrap.scss" type="text/css" media="all">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

and the gulp file:

```
gulp.task('test', function () {
    return gulp.src('path_to_html')
        .pipe(gulp.src('path_to_styles'))
        .pipe(gulpif('path_to_styles', sass()))
        .pipe('path_to_styles'.restore())
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('target_folder'));
});
```

How can I firstly transform .scss into .css and then use use-ref.

Comment: since sass compiles to a single css file i ended up just referencing the sass output css file in my html and don't use inject for that file

Answer (score 0):

On my project i use `gulp-rename` to do stuff like that.

```
.pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
```

Install [gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename).

And on your task do this:

```
gulp.task('test', function () {
    return gulp.src('path_to_html')
        .pipe(gulp.src('path_to_styles'))
        .pipe(gulpif('path_to_styles', sass()))
        .pipe('path_to_styles'.restore())
        .pipe(rename({
            extname: ".css"
        }))
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('target_folder'));
});
```